# JAXB "unknown location" when using catalog

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I am having difficulties using JAXB 2.2 to generate Java classes when types in an *imported* schema are referenced.  I believe catalogs are used to accomplish what I want.

I have two XSD files:

---

### ProductsCommonTypes.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/ProductsCommonTypes"
   xmlns="http://www.example.com/ProductsCommonTypes" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xs:simpleType name="nonEmptyString">
      <xs:annotation>
         <xs:documentation>A type that will require a non-empty string value be present
         </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:pattern value="(\s*[^\s]\s*)+"></xs:pattern>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

---

### Products.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:p="http://www.example.com/Products"
   targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/Products" xmlns:common="http://www.example.com/ProductsCommonTypes"
   elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xs:import schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/ProductsCommonTypes" namespace="http://www.example.com/ProductsCommonTypes"/>
   <xs:element name="products">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="common:nonEmptyString" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

### ProductsSchemaCatalog.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE catalog
    PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN"
           "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
    <public publicId="http://www.example.com/ProductsCommonTypes" uri="ProductsCommonTypes.xsd"/>
</catalog>
```

When I generate the classes using *JAXB-Generate Classes...*, I specify the path to the ProductsSchemaCatalog.xml file for the Catalog.

The output I get is:

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
[INFO] generating code
unknown location

com\example\xml\products\ObjectFactory.java
com\example\xml\products\Products.java
com\example\xml\products\package-info.java
```

Not sure if it matters or not, but Eclipse validates all files properly.

Both of my XSD files have been added to my Eclipse XML Catalog using *Namespace name* as a key type and the NameSpace for the Key.

What is causing the **unknown location** message in the output?

Comment: The configuration seems work fine . Above is there the real XSD? anyway is there some stacktrace of error?

Comment: Did you try to use the -d command to specify where to extract the files?
For example:
C:\JAVA_HOME\bin> xjc -d C:\directory\Path\Outside\JavaHome(e.g. on the desktop) yourAwesome.xsd

I had a similar problem and the solution was using the command "-d" and creating a folder named "generated" outside JAVA_HOME. 

For more info, check out https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnbal/index.html